# Netgear NightHawk Dual Band Unable to Connect to Android Box

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, android

Purchased an Android Box for Streaming TV and using a Netgear Nighthawk for connectivity. I wanted the Android box to connect to 5GHz instead of 2.4GHz. It connects w/o a problem to 2.4Ghz but ONLY shows "Connecting" when trying to connect to 5GHz. Both profiles (2.4Ghz and 5GHz) have the same password, but it appears it will not connect to 5GHz. Any thoughts on why it just show "Connecting" and no error message?

Comment: Do both networks, 2.4 ghz and 5 ghz, have different names?

Comment: What's the make and model of the "Android box"? it may be the adapter, make sure you don't have your network settings set to mixed aes/tkip. You want AES only.